# Run JavaScript "for each file or folder" that's selected in Finder, using a macOS Automator service workflow

Tags: javascript, applescript, automator, finder

Trying to write a service where I can control+click multiple files, run an Automator service that copies the paths to those files to clipboard, and performs a few string replacements.

So here's what I got:

**1. The input**

[image: the input]

**2. Run JavaScript**

```
function run(input, parameters) {

    var path = String(input);
    path = path.replace(/^.+\/websites\//, "/"); // this should remove some stuff off the paths up until /websites/

    return path;
}
```

**3. Copy to Clipboard**

**The problem**: Only the last file is copied to clipboard.

How do I fix this so I can select multiple files, have Automator loop over all paths, do the necessary text replacements using JavaScript, and copy all new paths to clipboard ?

I've tried `for (path in input) { ... }` but then path is a string with input's index value...

PS: How would I do this using AppleScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is JavaScript, you have the luxury of using `map` that means looping in the traditional sense isn't required:

```js
function run(input) {
    return input.map( fp => fp.replace(/^.+\/websites\//. '/') );
}
```

One thing you should check (which I haven't because I'm not completely clear about the context) is that the `input` receives the paths in posix format, e.g. *`/path/to/something`*, rather than the old HFS format, e.g. *`Macintosh HD:path:to:something`*.